# How to get selected option via class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the selected option of my select so i tried this:

```
var lastname = $(".lastname")[0].find(":selected").text();
```

I already tried this but with the id instead of the class. There it works. Unforrunately I have to access via class.

I get the Error „[0]. find is not a function“

Comment: If you want the selected option do `$('.lastname option:selected').text()`. Or if it's because you have multiple selects with the same class you can do `$('.lastname:eq(0) option:selected').text()`

Comment: `find is not a function` - your issue is that `$(".lastname")[0]` gives you a DOM node which does not have a `.find` method, to continue with jquery `$(".lastname").eq(0).find...`

Comment: FYI: To be aware of:  `:eq(0)` is *deprecated* : https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/ *the :eq pseudo-class is deprecated. Remove it from your selectors and filter the results later using .eq().*

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to use class name if its working with id ? Class name can be common across multiple controls while id is unique.